# Iteration failure in radixsort aka bucket sort algorithm,Radix sort inefficient because it assigns wrong size for bucket 0 according to the unit test

Tags: python, algorithm, radix-sort, array-algorithms, bucket-sort

For one of my assignment, I am asked to implement a radix sort algorithm. Here is the code that was written so far:

```
class RadixSort:
    def __init__(self):
        self.base = 7
        self.bucket_list_history = []

    def get_bucket_list_history(self):
        return self.bucket_list_history

    def sort(self, input_array):
        """
        Sorts a given list using radix sort in descending order
        @param input_array: list to be sorted
        @returns: a sorted list
        """
        self.bucket_list_history.clear()  # Clear history list at the beginning of sorting

        max_value = max(input_array)  # Find the maximum value in the input array
        exp = 1  # Current digit place

        while max_value // exp > 0:
            bucket_list = [[] for _ in range(self.base)]  # Create empty buckets

            for num in input_array:
                digit = (num // exp) % self.base  # Get the digit at the current place value
                bucket_list[digit].append(num)  # Assign the number to the respective bucket

            self._add_bucket_list_to_history(bucket_list)  # Add the bucket list snapshot to history

            input_array = []  # Clear the input array
            for bucket in bucket_list:
                input_array.extend(bucket)  # Reconstruct the input array from the buckets

            exp *= self.base  # Move to the next digit place

        return input_array[::-1]  # Return the sorted list in descending order

    # TODO

    # Helper functions

    def _add_bucket_list_to_history(self, bucket_list):
        """
        This method creates a snapshot (clone) of the bucket list and adds it to the bucket list history.
        @param bucket_list: current bucket list after assigning elements to be sorted to the buckets
        @param iteration: current iteration index
        """
        print(bucket_list)
        arr_clone = []
        for i in range(0, len(bucket_list)):
            arr_clone.append([])
            for j in bucket_list[i]:
                arr_clone[i].append(j)
        self.bucket_list_history.append(arr_clone)
```

I was able to successfully sort the array in the end, however, I continuously get these errors:

```
[[21, 0], [], [2123], [10216, 402, 10123515], [164504, 5142], [33, 614, 21523], [6411]]
[[0], [402, 164504, 21523], [2123, 10123515], [21, 10216, 614], [33], [6411], [5142]]
[[0, 21, 33], [402, 2123], [], [], [164504, 10123515, 6411], [21523, 10216, 614], [5142]]
[[0, 21, 33, 5142], [402, 10216, 614], [10123515], [164504], [6411], [], [2123, 21523]]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123], [21523], [5142, 10123515, 6411], [], [10216], [164504], []]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123, 5142, 10123515, 6411, 10216], [21523], [164504], [], [], [], []]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123, 5142, 6411, 10216, 21523], [164504], [10123515], [], [], [], []]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123, 5142, 6411, 10216, 21523, 164504], [], [], [], [], [10123515], []]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123, 5142, 6411, 10216, 21523, 164504], [10123515], [], [], [], [], []]

Radix sort of input array [33, 614, 10216, 2123, 21523, 164504, 5142, 402, 6411, 21, 10123515, 0] failed in iteration 1 on bucket 0 because of wrong size
2 != 1

Expected :1
Actual   :2
<Click to see difference>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sakops/Schreibtisch/artificial intelligence/algos and datastructures/uebung/sorting/code/radix_sort/unit_test_radix_sort.py", line 97, in test_radix_sort_bucket_lists_iteration_1
    self.assertEqual(1, len(bucket_list_history[it_idx][0]), err_msg + " 0 because of wrong size")
AssertionError: 1 != 2 : Radix sort of input array [33, 614, 10216, 2123, 21523, 164504, 5142, 402, 6411, 21, 10123515, 0] failed in iteration 1 on bucket 0 because of wrong size

[[21, 0], [], [2123], [10216, 402, 10123515], [164504, 5142], [33, 614, 21523], [6411]]
[[0], [402, 164504, 21523], [2123, 10123515], [21, 10216, 614], [33], [6411], [5142]]
[[0, 21, 33], [402, 2123], [], [], [164504, 10123515, 6411], [21523, 10216, 614], [5142]]
[[0, 21, 33, 5142], [402, 10216, 614], [10123515], [164504], [6411], [], [2123, 21523]]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123], [21523], [5142, 10123515, 6411], [], [10216], [164504], []]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123, 5142, 10123515, 6411, 10216], [21523], [164504], [], [], [], []]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123, 5142, 6411, 10216, 21523], [164504], [10123515], [], [], [], []]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123, 5142, 6411, 10216, 21523, 164504], [], [], [], [], [10123515], []]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123, 5142, 6411, 10216, 21523, 164504], [10123515], [], [], [], [], []]

Radix sort of input array [33, 614, 10216, 2123, 21523, 164504, 5142, 402, 6411, 21, 10123515, 0] failed in iteration 2 on bucket 0 because of wrong size
1 != 0

Expected :0
Actual   :1
<Click to see difference>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sakops/Schreibtisch/artificial intelligence/algos and datastructures/uebung/sorting/code/radix_sort/unit_test_radix_sort.py", line 135, in test_radix_sort_bucket_lists_iteration_2
    self.assertEqual(0, len(bucket_list_history[it_idx][0]), err_msg + " 0 because of wrong size")
AssertionError: 0 != 1 : Radix sort of input array [33, 614, 10216, 2123, 21523, 164504, 5142, 402, 6411, 21, 10123515, 0] failed in iteration 2 on bucket 0 because of wrong size

[[21, 0], [], [2123], [10216, 402, 10123515], [164504, 5142], [33, 614, 21523], [6411]]
[[0], [402, 164504, 21523], [2123, 10123515], [21, 10216, 614], [33], [6411], [5142]]
[[0, 21, 33], [402, 2123], [], [], [164504, 10123515, 6411], [21523, 10216, 614], [5142]]
[[0, 21, 33, 5142], [402, 10216, 614], [10123515], [164504], [6411], [], [2123, 21523]]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123], [21523], [5142, 10123515, 6411], [], [10216], [164504], []]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123, 5142, 10123515, 6411, 10216], [21523], [164504], [], [], [], []]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123, 5142, 6411, 10216, 21523], [164504], [10123515], [], [], [], []]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123, 5142, 6411, 10216, 21523, 164504], [], [], [], [], [10123515], []]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123, 5142, 6411, 10216, 21523, 164504], [10123515], [], [], [], [], []]

Radix sort of input array [33, 614, 10216, 2123, 21523, 164504, 5142, 402, 6411, 21, 10123515, 0] failed in iteration 3 on bucket 0 because of wrong size
3 != 1

Expected :1
Actual   :3
<Click to see difference>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sakops/Schreibtisch/artificial intelligence/algos and datastructures/uebung/sorting/code/radix_sort/unit_test_radix_sort.py", line 172, in test_radix_sort_bucket_lists_iteration_3
    self.assertEqual(1, len(bucket_list_history[it_idx][0]), err_msg + " 0 because of wrong size")
AssertionError: 1 != 3 : Radix sort of input array [33, 614, 10216, 2123, 21523, 164504, 5142, 402, 6411, 21, 10123515, 0] failed in iteration 3 on bucket 0 because of wrong size

[[21, 0], [], [2123], [10216, 402, 10123515], [164504, 5142], [33, 614, 21523], [6411]]
[[0], [402, 164504, 21523], [2123, 10123515], [21, 10216, 614], [33], [6411], [5142]]
[[0, 21, 33], [402, 2123], [], [], [164504, 10123515, 6411], [21523, 10216, 614], [5142]]
[[0, 21, 33, 5142], [402, 10216, 614], [10123515], [164504], [6411], [], [2123, 21523]]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123], [21523], [5142, 10123515, 6411], [], [10216], [164504], []]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123, 5142, 10123515, 6411, 10216], [21523], [164504], [], [], [], []]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123, 5142, 6411, 10216, 21523], [164504], [10123515], [], [], [], []]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123, 5142, 6411, 10216, 21523, 164504], [], [], [], [], [10123515], []]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123, 5142, 6411, 10216, 21523, 164504], [10123515], [], [], [], [], []]

Radix sort of input array [33, 614, 10216, 2123, 21523, 164504, 5142, 402, 6411, 21, 10123515, 0] failed in iteration 4 on bucket 0 because of wrong size
4 != 1

Expected :1
Actual   :4
<Click to see difference>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sakops/Schreibtisch/artificial intelligence/algos and datastructures/uebung/sorting/code/radix_sort/unit_test_radix_sort.py", line 209, in test_radix_sort_bucket_lists_iteration_4
    self.assertEqual(1, len(bucket_list_history[it_idx][0]), err_msg + " 0 because of wrong size")
AssertionError: 1 != 4 : Radix sort of input array [33, 614, 10216, 2123, 21523, 164504, 5142, 402, 6411, 21, 10123515, 0] failed in iteration 4 on bucket 0 because of wrong size

[[21, 0], [], [2123], [10216, 402, 10123515], [164504, 5142], [33, 614, 21523], [6411]]
[[0], [402, 164504, 21523], [2123, 10123515], [21, 10216, 614], [33], [6411], [5142]]
[[0, 21, 33], [402, 2123], [], [], [164504, 10123515, 6411], [21523, 10216, 614], [5142]]
[[0, 21, 33, 5142], [402, 10216, 614], [10123515], [164504], [6411], [], [2123, 21523]]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123], [21523], [5142, 10123515, 6411], [], [10216], [164504], []]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123, 5142, 10123515, 6411, 10216], [21523], [164504], [], [], [], []]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123, 5142, 6411, 10216, 21523], [164504], [10123515], [], [], [], []]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123, 5142, 6411, 10216, 21523, 164504], [], [], [], [], [10123515], []]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123, 5142, 6411, 10216, 21523, 164504], [10123515], [], [], [], [], []]

Radix sort of input array [33, 614, 10216, 2123, 21523, 164504, 5142, 402, 6411, 21, 10123515, 0] failed in iteration 5 on bucket 0 because of wrong size
6 != 1

Expected :1
Actual   :6
<Click to see difference>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sakops/Schreibtisch/artificial intelligence/algos and datastructures/uebung/sorting/code/radix_sort/unit_test_radix_sort.py", line 246, in test_radix_sort_bucket_lists_iteration_5
    self.assertEqual(1, len(bucket_list_history[it_idx][0]), err_msg + " 0 because of wrong size")
AssertionError: 1 != 6 : Radix sort of input array [33, 614, 10216, 2123, 21523, 164504, 5142, 402, 6411, 21, 10123515, 0] failed in iteration 5 on bucket 0 because of wrong size

[[21, 0], [], [2123], [10216, 402, 10123515], [164504, 5142], [33, 614, 21523], [6411]]
[[0], [402, 164504, 21523], [2123, 10123515], [21, 10216, 614], [33], [6411], [5142]]
[[0, 21, 33], [402, 2123], [], [], [164504, 10123515, 6411], [21523, 10216, 614], [5142]]
[[0, 21, 33, 5142], [402, 10216, 614], [10123515], [164504], [6411], [], [2123, 21523]]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123], [21523], [5142, 10123515, 6411], [], [10216], [164504], []]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123, 5142, 10123515, 6411, 10216], [21523], [164504], [], [], [], []]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123, 5142, 6411, 10216, 21523], [164504], [10123515], [], [], [], []]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123, 5142, 6411, 10216, 21523, 164504], [], [], [], [], [10123515], []]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123, 5142, 6411, 10216, 21523, 164504], [10123515], [], [], [], [], []]

Radix sort of input array [33, 614, 10216, 2123, 21523, 164504, 5142, 402, 6411, 21, 10123515, 0] failed in iteration 6 on bucket 0 because of wrong size
10 != 0

Expected :0
Actual   :10
<Click to see difference>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sakops/Schreibtisch/artificial intelligence/algos and datastructures/uebung/sorting/code/radix_sort/unit_test_radix_sort.py", line 283, in test_radix_sort_bucket_lists_iteration_6
    self.assertEqual(0, len(bucket_list_history[it_idx][0]), err_msg + " 0 because of wrong size")
AssertionError: 0 != 10 : Radix sort of input array [33, 614, 10216, 2123, 21523, 164504, 5142, 402, 6411, 21, 10123515, 0] failed in iteration 6 on bucket 0 because of wrong size

[[21, 0], [], [2123], [10216, 402, 10123515], [164504, 5142], [33, 614, 21523], [6411]]
[[0], [402, 164504, 21523], [2123, 10123515], [21, 10216, 614], [33], [6411], [5142]]
[[0, 21, 33], [402, 2123], [], [], [164504, 10123515, 6411], [21523, 10216, 614], [5142]]
[[0, 21, 33, 5142], [402, 10216, 614], [10123515], [164504], [6411], [], [2123, 21523]]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123], [21523], [5142, 10123515, 6411], [], [10216], [164504], []]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123, 5142, 10123515, 6411, 10216], [21523], [164504], [], [], [], []]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123, 5142, 6411, 10216, 21523], [164504], [10123515], [], [], [], []]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123, 5142, 6411, 10216, 21523, 164504], [], [], [], [], [10123515], []]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123, 5142, 6411, 10216, 21523, 164504], [10123515], [], [], [], [], []]

Radix sort of input array [33, 614, 10216, 2123, 21523, 164504, 5142, 402, 6411, 21, 10123515, 0] failed in iteration 7 on bucket 0 because of wrong size
10 != 0

Expected :0
Actual   :10
<Click to see difference>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sakops/Schreibtisch/artificial intelligence/algos and datastructures/uebung/sorting/code/radix_sort/unit_test_radix_sort.py", line 320, in test_radix_sort_bucket_lists_iteration_7
    self.assertEqual(0, len(bucket_list_history[it_idx][0]), err_msg + " 0 because of wrong size")
AssertionError: 0 != 10 : Radix sort of input array [33, 614, 10216, 2123, 21523, 164504, 5142, 402, 6411, 21, 10123515, 0] failed in iteration 7 on bucket 0 because of wrong size

[[21, 0], [], [2123], [10216, 402, 10123515], [164504, 5142], [33, 614, 21523], [6411]]
[[0], [402, 164504, 21523], [2123, 10123515], [21, 10216, 614], [33], [6411], [5142]]
[[0, 21, 33], [402, 2123], [], [], [164504, 10123515, 6411], [21523, 10216, 614], [5142]]
[[0, 21, 33, 5142], [402, 10216, 614], [10123515], [164504], [6411], [], [2123, 21523]]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123], [21523], [5142, 10123515, 6411], [], [10216], [164504], []]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123, 5142, 10123515, 6411, 10216], [21523], [164504], [], [], [], []]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123, 5142, 6411, 10216, 21523], [164504], [10123515], [], [], [], []]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123, 5142, 6411, 10216, 21523, 164504], [], [], [], [], [10123515], []]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123, 5142, 6411, 10216, 21523, 164504], [10123515], [], [], [], [], []]

Radix sort of input array [33, 614, 10216, 2123, 21523, 164504, 5142, 402, 6411, 21, 10123515, 0] failed in iteration 8 on bucket 0 because of wrong size
11 != 0

Expected :0
Actual   :11
<Click to see difference>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sakops/Schreibtisch/artificial intelligence/algos and datastructures/uebung/sorting/code/radix_sort/unit_test_radix_sort.py", line 357, in test_radix_sort_bucket_lists_iteration_8
    self.assertEqual(0, len(bucket_list_history[it_idx][0]), err_msg + " 0 because of wrong size")
AssertionError: 0 != 11 : Radix sort of input array [33, 614, 10216, 2123, 21523, 164504, 5142, 402, 6411, 21, 10123515, 0] failed in iteration 8 on bucket 0 because of wrong size

[[], [], [], [], [4, 4, 4], [], [111]]
[[4, 4, 4], [111], [], [], [], [], []]
[[4, 4, 4], [], [111], [], [], [], []]
[[0], [15], [], [234], [5562], [12], []]
[[0], [12], [15], [5562], [], [234], []]
[[0, 12, 15], [5562], [], [], [234], [], []]
[[0, 12, 15, 234], [], [5562], [], [], [], []]
[[0, 12, 15, 234], [], [5562], [], [], [], []]
[[21, 0], [], [2123], [10216, 402, 10123515], [164504, 5142], [33, 614, 21523], [6411]]
[[0], [402, 164504, 21523], [2123, 10123515], [21, 10216, 614], [33], [6411], [5142]]
[[0, 21, 33], [402, 2123], [], [], [164504, 10123515, 6411], [21523, 10216, 614], [5142]]
[[0, 21, 33, 5142], [402, 10216, 614], [10123515], [164504], [6411], [], [2123, 21523]]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123], [21523], [5142, 10123515, 6411], [], [10216], [164504], []]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123, 5142, 10123515, 6411, 10216], [21523], [164504], [], [], [], []]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123, 5142, 6411, 10216, 21523], [164504], [10123515], [], [], [], []]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123, 5142, 6411, 10216, 21523, 164504], [], [], [], [], [10123515], []]
[[0, 21, 33, 402, 614, 2123, 5142, 6411, 10216, 21523, 164504], [10123515], [], [], [], [], []]
[[], [1], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Here is the test code:

def deduct_pts(value):
global points
points = points - value
if points < 0:
points = 0

def resolve_amount_of_pts_to_deduct(argument):
pool = {
"test_radix_sort_result": 3,
"test_radix_sort_result_one_element": 1,
"test_radix_sort_equal_elements": 1,
"test_radix_sort_presorted_array": 1,
"test_radix_sort_bucket_lists_iteration_1": 0.75,
"test_radix_sort_bucket_lists_iteration_2": 0.75,
"test_radix_sort_bucket_lists_iteration_3": 0.75,
"test_radix_sort_bucket_lists_iteration_4": 0.75,
"test_radix_sort_bucket_lists_iteration_5": 0.75,
"test_radix_sort_bucket_lists_iteration_6": 0.75,
"test_radix_sort_bucket_lists_iteration_7": 0.75,
"test_radix_sort_bucket_lists_iteration_8": 0.75,
}
# resolve the pts to deduct from pool
return pool.get(argument, 0)

class UnitTestTemplate(unittest.TestCase):
def setUp(self):
pass

```
####################################################
# Definition of test cases
####################################################

def test_radix_sort_result(self):
    r = RadixSort()
    result = r.sort(test_array.copy())
    test_array.sort(reverse=True)
    for i in range(0, len(test_array)):
        self.assertEqual(test_array[i], result[i],
                         f"ERROR: sort with input sequence {test_array} failed at index {i}: {result}")

def test_radix_sort_result_one_element(self):
    r = RadixSort()
    result = r.sort([1])
    self.assertEqual(1, result[0], f"ERROR: sort with input sequence [1] failed at index 1: {result}")
    self.assertEqual(1, len(result), f"ERROR: sort with input sequence [1] failed because of incorrect size")

def test_radix_sort_equal_elements(self):
    r = RadixSort()
    result = r.sort(test_array_equals.copy())
    test_array_equals.sort(reverse=True)
    for i in range(0, len(test_array_equals)):
        self.assertEqual(test_array_equals[i], result[i],
                         f"ERROR: sort with input sequence {test_array_equals} failed at index {i}: {result}")

def test_radix_sort_presorted_array(self):
    r = RadixSort()
    result = r.sort(test_array_presorted.copy())
    test_array_presorted.sort(reverse=True)
    for i in range(0, len(test_array_presorted)):
        self.assertEqual(test_array_presorted[i], result[i],
                         f"ERROR: sort with input sequence {test_array_presorted} failed at index {i}: {result}")

def test_radix_sort_bucket_lists_iteration_1(self):
    it_idx = 0
    err_msg = f"Radix sort of input array {test_array} failed in iteration {it_idx + 1} on bucket"
    r = RadixSort()
    r.sort(test_array.copy())
    bucket_list_history = r.get_bucket_list_history()

    self.assertTrue(len(bucket_list_history) > 0, "ERROR: bucket_list_history is empty")
    self.assertTrue(len(bucket_list_history[it_idx]) >= 7,
                    f"ERROR: bucket_list_history[{it_idx}] is of wrong size, must contain 7 buckets")

    self.assertEqual(1, len(bucket_list_history[it_idx][0]), err_msg + " 0 because of wrong size")
    self.assertTrue(10216 in bucket_list_history[it_idx][0], err_msg + " 0 because of missing element 10216")

    self.assertEqual(1, len(bucket_list_history[it_idx][1]), err_msg + " 1 because of wrong size")
    self.assertTrue(10123515 in bucket_list_history[it_idx][1], err_msg + " 1 because of missing element 10123515")

    self.assertEqual(2, len(bucket_list_history[it_idx][2]), err_msg + " 2 because of wrong size")
    self.assertTrue(614 in bucket_list_history[it_idx][2], err_msg + " 2 because of missing element 614")
    self.assertTrue(164504 in bucket_list_history[it_idx][2], err_msg + " 2 because of missing element 164504")

    self.assertEqual(3, len(bucket_list_history[it_idx][3]), err_msg + " 3 because of wrong size")
    self.assertTrue(33 in bucket_list_history[it_idx][3], err_msg + " 3 because of missing element 33")
    self.assertTrue(2123 in bucket_list_history[it_idx][3], err_msg + " 3 because of missing element 2123")
    self.assertTrue(21523 in bucket_list_history[it_idx][3], err_msg + " 3 because of missing element 21523")

    self.assertEqual(2, len(bucket_list_history[it_idx][4]), err_msg + " 4 because of wrong size")
    self.assertTrue(5142 in bucket_list_history[it_idx][4], err_msg + " 4 because of missing element 5142")
    self.assertTrue(402 in bucket_list_history[it_idx][4], err_msg + " 4 because of missing element 402")

    self.assertEqual(2, len(bucket_list_history[it_idx][5]), err_msg + " 5 because of wrong size")
    self.assertTrue(6411 in bucket_list_history[it_idx][5], err_msg + " 5 because of missing element 6411")
    self.assertTrue(21 in bucket_list_history[it_idx][5], err_msg + " 5 because of missing element 21")

    self.assertEqual(1, len(bucket_list_history[it_idx][6]), err_msg + " 6 because of wrong size")
    self.assertTrue(0 in bucket_list_history[it_idx][6], err_msg + " 6 because of missing element 0")
    print(len(bucket_list_history[it_idx][6]))
```

Since the test code hase over 300 lines, I posted the first 100

For troubleshooting purposes I print out each iteration and apparently my bucket is continuously of the wrong size, any idea on how to resolve this?

Thank you

Comment: Your code is using a base of 7 but your unit test might be implicitly assuming base 10. Your test, however, seems to be expecting that there should be only one element in bucket 0 at the first iteration. I believe this is not correct based on the input array and the expected behavior of radix sort. Without seeing the actual test code it's difficult to say for sure, but it looks like there might be an error in your unit test's expected outputs or perhaps a misunderstanding of how radix sort should behave.

Comment: I have tried base 10 as well, but in the unit test base 7 is used. When assigning 7 to the exp variable this error is brought up: 
AssertionError: False is not true : Radix sort of input array [33, 614, 10216, 2123, 21523, 164504, 5142, 402, 6411, 21, 10123515, 0] failed in iteration 1 on bucket 0 because of missing element 10216

Comment: I have added the first snippets from the test.py, however, even in the class self.base=7, base 7 is assumed